# Python menu update

Tags: python, loops, menu, tkinter

I am developing a GUI in Python in which a team is selected from a menu. When a team is selected, a command should be executed in which a value PD is calculated based on values in the slider. I'm having two problems. 1) the value is not updated from the slider values. I am using the .get() function but it doesn't seem to be working. 2) the sliders are getting stacked on each other when a new team is selected. How do I clear the first set so a new set is created for each team? Here is my code: any thoughts?

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import Tkinter


root = Tk()
root.title("NBA Point Differentials Predictor")
root.geometry("300x680")

mb =  Menubutton (root, text = "Select Team", relief = RAISED, pady = 8)
mb.grid()
mb.menu  =  Menu ( mb, tearoff = 0)
mb["menu"]  =  mb.menu


def sel():
    selection = "Point differential = " + str(PD)
    label.config(text = selection)

FGP = DoubleVar();TPP = DoubleVar(); FTP = DoubleVar(); ORB = DoubleVar(); TRB = DoubleVar();
AST = DoubleVar(); STL = DoubleVar(); BLK = DoubleVar(); TOV = DoubleVar(); PF = DoubleVar(); 

def ATL():

    index = 1

    if index == 1: 

        FGP_mean = 0.47; TPP_mean = 0.4; FTP_mean = 0.78; ORB_mean = 8.5;
        TRB_mean = 40.6; AST_mean = 25.8; STL_mean = 9.06; BLK_mean = 4.63;
        TOV_mean = 13.5; PF_mean = 17.7;

        slider_order = [5, 1, 9, 7, 6, 3, 4, 2, 8, 10]

        for x in slider_order:

            if x == 1:
                scale1 = Scale(root, from_=0, to=1, resolution = 0.01, variable = FGP, orient = HORIZONTAL, label = "Field goal percentage")
                scale1.set(FGP_mean)
                scale1.grid()
            elif x == 2:
                scale2 = Scale(root, from_=0, to=1, resolution = 0.01, variable = TPP, orient = HORIZONTAL, label = "3-point field goal percentage")
                scale2.set(TPP_mean)
                scale2.grid()
            elif x == 3:
                scale3 = Scale(root, from_=0, to=1, resolution = 0.01, variable = FTP, orient = HORIZONTAL, label = "Free throw percentage")
                scale3.set(FTP_mean)
                scale3.grid()
            elif x == 4:
                scale4 = Scale(root, from_=0, to=50, variable = ORB, orient = HORIZONTAL, label = "Offensive rebounds")
                scale4.set(ORB_mean)
                scale4.grid()
            elif x == 5:
                scale5 = Scale(root, from_=0, to=100, variable = TRB, orient = HORIZONTAL, label = "Total rebounds")
                scale5.set(TRB_mean)
                scale5.grid()
            elif x == 6:
                scale6 = Scale(root, from_=0, to=50, variable = AST, orient = HORIZONTAL, label = "Assists")
                scale6.set(AST_mean)
                scale6.grid()
            elif x == 7:
                scale7 = Scale(root, from_=0, to=30, variable = STL, orient = HORIZONTAL, label = "Steals")
                scale7.set(STL_mean)
                scale7.grid()
            elif x == 8:
                scale8 = Scale(root, from_=0, to=30, variable = BLK, orient = HORIZONTAL, label = "Blocks")
                scale8.set(BLK_mean)
                scale8.grid()
            elif x == 9:
                scale9 = Scale(root, from_=0, to=50, variable = TOV, orient = HORIZONTAL, label = "Turnovers")
                scale9.set(TOV_mean)
                scale9.grid()
            else:  
                scale10 = Scale(root, from_=0, to=50, variable = PF, orient = HORIZONTAL, label = "Personal fouls")
                scale10.set(PF_mean)
                scale10.grid()

        global PD

        PD = -123.9319 + 114.58945*FGP.get() + 12.48279*TPP.get() + 14.62438*FTP.get() - 0.41907*ORB.get() + 1.36049*TRB.get() + 0.46082*AST.get() + 1.17966*STL.get() + 0.18258*BLK.get() -1.16002*TOV.get() + 0.02497*PF.get()


def BOS():

    index = 2

    if index == 2:

        FGP_mean = 0.44; TPP_mean = 0.32; FTP_mean = 0.76; ORB_mean = 11.14;
        TRB_mean = 43.94; AST_mean = 24.22; STL_mean = 8.038; BLK_mean = 3.59;
        TOV_mean = 13.29; PF_mean = 21.24;

        slider_order = [1, 5, 9, 7, 4, 2, 10, 6, 3, 8]

        for x in slider_order:

            if x == 1:
                scale1 = Scale(root, from_=0, to=1, resolution = 0.01, variable = FGP, orient = HORIZONTAL, label = "Field goal percentage")
                scale1.set(FGP_mean)
                scale1.grid()
            elif x == 2:
                scale2 = Scale(root, from_=0, to=1, resolution = 0.01, variable = TPP, orient = HORIZONTAL, label = "3-point field goal percentage")
                scale2.set(TPP_mean)
                scale2.grid()
            elif x == 3:
                scale3 = Scale(root, from_=0, to=1, resolution = 0.01, variable = FTP, orient = HORIZONTAL, label = "Free throw percentage")
                scale3.set(FTP_mean)
                scale3.grid()
            elif x == 4:
                scale4 = Scale(root, from_=0, to=50, variable = ORB, orient = HORIZONTAL, label = "Offensive rebounds")
                scale4.set(ORB_mean)
                scale4.grid()
            elif x == 5:
                scale5 = Scale(root, from_=0, to=100, variable = TRB, orient = HORIZONTAL, label = "Total rebounds")
                scale5.set(TRB_mean)
                scale5.grid()
            elif x == 6:
                scale6 = Scale(root, from_=0, to=50, variable = AST, orient = HORIZONTAL, label = "Assists")
                scale6.set(AST_mean)
                scale6.grid()
            elif x == 7:
                scale7 = Scale(root, from_=0, to=30, variable = STL, orient = HORIZONTAL, label = "Steals")
                scale7.set(STL_mean)
                scale7.grid()
            elif x == 8:
                scale8 = Scale(root, from_=0, to=30, variable = BLK, orient = HORIZONTAL, label = "Blocks")
                scale8.set(BLK_mean)
                scale8.grid()
            elif x == 9:
                scale9 = Scale(root, from_=0, to=50, variable = TOV, orient = HORIZONTAL, label = "Turnovers")
                scale9.set(TOV_mean)
                scale9.grid()
            else:  
                scale10 = Scale(root, from_=0, to=50, variable = PF, orient = HORIZONTAL, label = "Personal fouls")
                scale10.set(PF_mean)
                scale10.grid()

        global PD

        PD = -95.6789 + 135.5622*FGP.get() + 13.2779*TPP.get() + 7.1998*FTP.get() - 0.5649*ORB.get() + 1.0487*TRB.get() - 0.2041*AST.get() + 1.4290*STL.get() - 0.2492*BLK.get() - 1.2071*TOV.get() - 0.1919*PF.get()



def BRK():

    FGP_mean = 0.45; TPP_mean = 0.33; FTP_mean = 0.75; ORB_mean = 10.24;
    TRB_mean = 42.28; AST_mean = 20.94; STL_mean = 7.0; BLK_mean = 4.18;
    TOV_mean = 13.45; PF_mean = 19.0;

    slider_order = [5, 1, 7, 9, 2, 4, 3, 6, 10, 8]

    for x in slider_order:

        if x == 1:
            scale1 = Scale(root, from_=0, to=1, resolution = 0.01, variable = FGP, orient = HORIZONTAL, label = "Field goal percentage")
            scale1.set(FGP_mean)
            scale1.grid()
        elif x == 2:
            scale2 = Scale(root, from_=0, to=1, resolution = 0.01, variable = TPP, orient = HORIZONTAL, label = "3-point field goal percentage")
            scale2.set(TPP_mean)
            scale2.grid()
        elif x == 3:
            scale3 = Scale(root, from_=0, to=1, resolution = 0.01, variable = FTP, orient = HORIZONTAL, label = "Free throw percentage")
            scale3.set(FTP_mean)
            scale3.grid()
        elif x == 4:
            scale4 = Scale(root, from_=0, to=50, variable = ORB, orient = HORIZONTAL, label = "Offensive rebounds")
            scale4.set(ORB_mean)
            scale4.grid()
        elif x == 5:
            scale5 = Scale(root, from_=0, to=100, variable = TRB, orient = HORIZONTAL, label = "Total rebounds")
            scale5.set(TRB_mean)
            scale5.grid()
        elif x == 6:
            scale6 = Scale(root, from_=0, to=50, variable = AST, orient = HORIZONTAL, label = "Assists")
            scale6.set(AST_mean)
            scale6.grid()
        elif x == 7:
            scale7 = Scale(root, from_=0, to=30, variable = STL, orient = HORIZONTAL, label = "Steals")
            scale7.set(STL_mean)
            scale7.grid()
        elif x == 8:
            scale8 = Scale(root, from_=0, to=30, variable = BLK, orient = HORIZONTAL, label = "Blocks")
            scale8.set(BLK_mean)
            scale8.grid()
        elif x == 9:
            scale9 = Scale(root, from_=0, to=50, variable = TOV, orient = HORIZONTAL, label = "Turnovers")
            scale9.set(TOV_mean)
            scale9.grid()
        else:  
            scale10 = Scale(root, from_=0, to=50, variable = PF, orient = HORIZONTAL, label = "Personal fouls")
            scale10.set(PF_mean)
            scale10.grid()

    global PD

    PD = -143.6673 + 139.9460*FGP.get() + 29.1870*TPP.get() + 20.6729*FTP.get() - 0.8086*ORB.get() + 1.4133*TRB.get() - 0.2628*AST.get() + 1.8273*STL.get() + 0.3091*BLK.get() - 0.8778*TOV.get() + 0.1976*PF.get()

mb.menu.add_command(label="Atlanta Hawks", command=ATL)
mb.menu.add_command(label="Boston Celtics", command=BOS)
mb.menu.add_command(label="Brooklyn Nets", command=BRK)



app = Frame(root)
app.grid

button = Button(root, text = "Get Point Differential", command=sel)
button.grid()

label = Label(root)
label.grid()

root.config(menu=mb)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the calculations for `PD` are done within the `ATL`, `BOS` and `BRK` functions which are *only* called when you're selecting a team from the menu.

Cut the calculation out of these functions and put it into its own one. Now, you can *trace* the variables like `ORB`, `TRB` and such by using:

```
ORB.trace("w", calculate_points)
```

Comment: But each of the PD variables are unique to the ATL, BOS, etc. functions.

Comment: In this case, you can have a variable that contains either `ATL`, `BOS` or `BRK` which is updated when you select a team. In the `calculate_points` (or whatever it's going to be called) function, you can check against this variable and choose the specific calculation for the selected team. Anyway, I would *strongly* recommend you refactoring your GUI into a class; it helps getting those ugly globals out of the way.

Answer (score 0):

The following should fix the errors you're getting, as well as cleaning up the severe code duplication. The problem with values not being updated was as @TidB said: the calculation was carried out only when choosing a new team. The problem with sliders getting stacked on top of each other was because you were repeatedly creating new ones and putting them in the same place, rather than rearranging them with `grid(row=the_number_of_the_proper_row)`.

**NOTE**: I tested this in Python 3. The only difference for this program should be that in Python 2 it's `import Tkinter`, capital `T`, while in Python 3 it's `import tkinter`, lowercase `t`.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("NBA Point Differentials Predictor")
root.geometry("150x680")

mb =  Menubutton (root, text = "Select Team", relief = RAISED, pady = 8)
mb.grid()
mb.menu  =  Menu ( mb, tearoff = 0)
mb["menu"]  =  mb.menu

PD = []

def sel():
    selection = "Point differential = %0.3f" % (PD[0] + PD[1][0]*FGP.get() + PD[1][1]*TPP.get() + PD[1][2]*FTP.get() +
    PD[1][3]*ORB.get() + PD[1][4]*TRB.get() + PD[1][5]*AST.get() + PD[1][6]*STL.get() + PD[1][7]*BLK.get() +
    PD[1][8]*TOV.get() + PD[1][9]*PF.get())
    label.config(text = selection)

FGP, TPP, FTP, ORB, TRB, AST, STL, BLK, TOV, PF = (DoubleVar() for i in range(10))

all_scales = [
    Scale(root, from_=0, to=1, resolution = 0.01, variable = FGP, orient = HORIZONTAL, label = "Field goal percentage"),
    Scale(root, from_=0, to=1, resolution = 0.01, variable = TPP, orient = HORIZONTAL, label = "3-point field goal percentage"),
    Scale(root, from_=0, to=1, resolution = 0.01, variable = FTP, orient = HORIZONTAL, label = "Free throw percentage"),
    Scale(root, from_=0, to=50, variable = ORB, orient = HORIZONTAL, label = "Offensive rebounds"),
    Scale(root, from_=0, to=100, variable = TRB, orient = HORIZONTAL, label = "Total rebounds"),
    Scale(root, from_=0, to=50, variable = AST, orient = HORIZONTAL, label = "Assists"),
    Scale(root, from_=0, to=30, variable = STL, orient = HORIZONTAL, label = "Steals"),
    Scale(root, from_=0, to=30, variable = BLK, orient = HORIZONTAL, label = "Blocks"),
    Scale(root, from_=0, to=50, variable = TOV, orient = HORIZONTAL, label = "Turnovers"),
    Scale(root, from_=0, to=50, variable = PF, orient = HORIZONTAL, label = "Personal fouls")
    ]

def ATL(scales):
    slider_order = [5, 1, 9, 7, 6, 3, 4, 2, 8, 10]
    means = [0.47, 0.4, 0.78, 8.5, 40.6, 25.8, 9.06, 4.63, 13.5, 17.7]
    for order, scale, mean in zip(slider_order, scales, means):
            scale.set(mean)
            scale.grid(row=order+3)
    global PD
    PD = [-123.9319, [114.58945, 12.48279, 14.62438, -0.41907, 1.36049, 0.46082, 1.17966, 0.18258, -1.16002, 0.02497]]

def BOS(scales):
    slider_order = [1, 5, 9, 7, 4, 2, 10, 6, 3, 8]
    means = [0.44, 0.32, 0.76, 11.14, 43.94, 24.22, 8.038, 3.59, 13.29, 21.24]
    for order, scale, mean in zip(slider_order, scales, means):
            scale.set(mean)
            scale.grid(row=order+3)
    global PD
    PD = [-95.6789, [135.5622, 13.2779, 7.1998, -0.5649, 1.0487, -0.2041, 1.4290, -0.2492, -1.2071, -0.1919]]

def BRK(scales):
    slider_order = [5, 1, 7, 9, 2, 4, 3, 6, 10, 8]
    means = [0.45, 0.33, 0.75, 10.24, 42.28, 20.94, 7.0, 4.18, 13.45, 19.0]
    for order, scale, mean in zip(slider_order, scales, means):
            scale.set(mean)
            scale.grid(row=order+3)
    global PD
    PD = [-143.6673, [139.9460, 29.1870, 20.6729, -0.8086, 1.4133, -0.2628, 1.8273, 0.3091, -0.8778, 0.1976]]

mb.menu.add_command(label="Atlanta Hawks", command=lambda: ATL(all_scales))
mb.menu.add_command(label="Boston Celtics", command=lambda: BOS(all_scales))
mb.menu.add_command(label="Brooklyn Nets", command=lambda: BRK(all_scales))

app = Frame(root)
app.grid()

button = Button(app, text = "Get Point Differential", command=sel)
button.grid()

label = Label(app)
label.grid()

root.config(menu=mb)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Feel free to upvote/accept if this answer solved your problem.